# Problem making bundle install in the console when i change from ruby 2.3.7 to ruby 2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.5

i already try a lot o diferent way but cant solve this problem
.it seems that i cant install gems but i cant figure out why
already try with gem install bundler but steel doestn work

```sh
taller_integracion git:(develop) bundle install  
Traceback (most recent call last):
    7: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    6: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    5: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    4: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    3: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-0.9.26/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-0.9.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:124:in `start'
    1: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-0.9.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:377:in `start'
/Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-0.9.26/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/shell.rb:10:in `shell': uninitialized constant Thor::Base::Config (NameError)
```

and if i try with:

```
taller_integracion git:(develop) bundler install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    10: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
     9: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
     8: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
     7: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.0/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
     6: from /Users/seba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
     4: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
     2: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
/Users/seba/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.5/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:84:in `setup': undefined method `rubygems' for Bundler:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem. I was working on a small project hence I just updated ruby version in gemfile to 2.6.3 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

create a new gemset with this ruby version and then run

```
gem install bundler
```

to install bundler with the latest ruby.
Now run

```
bundle install
```

if bundle install does not work then try

```
bundle update
```

this should do the trick.
If you are still facing the same issue then let me know.

Comment: i still having the same error, i couldn't run bundle install and bundle update